# How can I display 2 menus (1 is images) responsive for mobile using media queries?

Tags: android, html, css

I am trying to enable my website navigation for responsive mobile viewing. 
I have one set of buttons that are made in CSS and then a set of buttons which are images (.png). When I use firefox and scale the width of the screen down I get the correct behavior but, for some reason the site shows the wrong layout on my phone. Can someone please tell me how I can display the site for mobile? I have included this in my html: meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0".

The site is here:
http://www.mattmacy.com/InternshipPortfolio/imagesTHREE/

Here is an image of the site on desktop:

[image]

The following is 2 screen shots of the page scaled down in firefox:

[image]

[image]

This is a screen grab of the image from my phone showing wrong layout:
[image]

I have used media queries for changing the layout when displayed on mobile. Please note that the CSS buttons display correctly when initially visited. Something to do with the #nowrap item (those are the tab-images) must be causing the page to extend horizontal. Here is as much of my CSS as can fit here:

```
  #nowrap{
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  }

  #nowrap, li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  }

  #A{
  position: relative;
  right: 0%;
  }

  #B{
  position: relative;
  right: -3%;
  }

  #C {
  position:relative;
  right: -6%;
   }

  #D{
  position: relative;
  right: -9%;
  }

  #whiteFile{
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border:4px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;

   }



 #item{
 position: relative;
 top: 160px;
  }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 #navbar li {display: block;
 vertical-align: middle;}
 #logo {position: relative;
  top: -1100px;
  }

 #nowrap, li{
 display: block;
 whitespace: normal;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #navbar li a {display: block;
        margin-top: 10px;}

 #A, #B, #C, #D
 {display: block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-top: 20px;
 position: relative;
 top: 500px;
    right: 0;}
```

Here is my HTML for the CSS menu and next my tab-like menu:

```
 <div id = "navbar">
 <ul>
 <li><a href= "index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href= "Artwork.html">Artwork</a></li>
 <li><a href= "Writings.html">Writings</a></li>
 <li><a href= "CV.html">CV</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img class="graphic" 
 src="ESOTERICSTUDIES.jpg" height="85" width="900"></a></div>
 </div>

 <body>
 <ul id="nowrap">
 <li><img id="A" src="GRAPHICSw.png" height="95" width="290"></li>
 <li><a href="VIDEOS.html#item"><img id="B" src="VIDEOSb.png" 
 height="95" width="290"></a></li>
 <li><a href="PHOTOS.html#item"><img id="C" src="PHOTOSb.png" 
 height="95" width="290"></a></li>
 <li><a href="WEBSITES.html#item"><img id="D" src="WEBSITESb.png" 
 height="95" width="290"></a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="whiteFile"></div>
 <h1 id="item">GRAPHICS</h1>
 </body>
```

Comment: Please add the code involved with this question so that people can have a better understanding and a potential solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to target the images in the media query.
I added the and seems to display correctly:

```
 #nowrap li img{
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px;}
```